# Suppressing the native dialog when clicking on a tel: link

Tags: android, html, iphone, browser, popup

I have been looking around to no avail regarding suppressing the dialog box on a mobile device when clicking on a telephone link.

We have this requirement to replace the existing native dialog on iPhone and Android with a custom popup from our website.

We have HTML5 at our disposal but for one basic site we are not to use javascript (for lower powered WAP phones).

Is there a way to suppress the phone native dialog coming from the browser (safari, chrome, firefox? ) via HTML from my site?

Thanks

Comment: Is the requirement for mobile webkit-based browsers only? Must the numbers be tel: links or can you wrap the numbers with something different to disguise them from the browser?

Comment: Will be webkit based... If we disguise them then we will still need a way to reach the phones dialler from the browser.

Comment: To be clear. We effectively want to rep[lace the native dialog with a HTML custom one. We still want to be able to make the phone call.

Comment: I think the whole *point* of the native dialog that appears before making a phone call, is to give the user the opportunity to accept or deny the attempt. This is important because the telephone number might be overseas, or a premium rate call, that the user must be able to deny (the monetary charges could be quite high). If any web page were able to simply make a call itself without the phone first asking for confirmation by the user, that would be a severe security problem ripe for exploitation by scammers.

Comment: I agree... however our client has requested to have a custom prompt on the page that will inform the user about the pending call. They just wanted to control the content of the prompt styled to that of our web application. If there is sufficent grounds for not having a custom dialog due to security reasons that could be a reason to convince them not to do it but I would be hesitant in expressing our application has security flaws in it without proof

Comment: It wouldn't be considered a security flaw in your application at all. It's a standard procedure enforced by Android to protect the user. There's no way to "promise" to the OS that you're going to behave yourself and therefore bypass the native dialog, because unscrupulous scammers would similarly "promise" the same thing.

Comment: Yes... If I get a compelling argument not to suppress the dialog then I will feed that back to them. If I can get information that the OS simply does not allow the browser to suppress the dialog then at least I can use that to convince them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're use case allows you to avoid using the tel: link format, you could put the numbers in something else that looks like a link and then have your webpage treat them however you wish. And to avoid having the browser auto-add links to numbers it thinks are telephone numbers, add the following html tag to your document's `<head>` (from the [Safari Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)):

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

Is this sufficient or is there more to your question that I'm not understanding?

**UPDATE**

With further clarification, it appears the desired result is to call up the native telephone dialer when a `tel://` link is pressed, but simply suppress the user prompt that precedes the dialing.

According to [RFC 3966: The tel URI for Telephone Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966), Section 11 Security Considerations:
*"Web clients and similar tools MUST NOT use the "tel" URI to place
telephone calls without the explicit consent of the user of that
client.  Placing calls automatically without appropriate user
confirmation may incur a number of risks..."*

So while it still may be possible that a parameter exists to suppress the alert, such as `&confirmation=false` or `&alert=no`, it is likely undocumented and different for each mobile OS. My guess would be that it doesn't exist.

**Possible Workarounds**

According to the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html):
 *"When a user taps a telephone link in a webpage, iOS displays an alert asking if the user really wants to dial the phone number and initiates dialing if the user accepts. When a user opens a URL with the tel scheme in a native application, iOS does not display an alert and initiates dialing without further prompting the user. However, a native application can be configured to display its own alert."*

So if your use case allows you to embed the website in a `UIWebView` and distribute it as an iOS app, suppressing the alert should be possible.

According to the [Android Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html):
*"[Use of the Dialer] requires your application to request the following permission in your manifest: `<uses-permission id="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`"*

So again, if your use case allows you to embed the website in an `android.webkit.WebView` and distribute it as an Android app, suppressing the alert appears to also be possible.

Comment: Great response... We already have an Android and iPhone app that we have applied this to. The Web Apps are for people without the downloaded application or on a device where no app is available. The impression I am getting (that I originally thought also) was that it is not possible to suppress the dialler confirmation popup from a web app. Since also we are dealing with numerous browsers (safari, chrome, opera, firefox) it would be extremely unreliable to trust any such suppression if it was remotely available.

Comment: I will leave the question open for a little longer to see if there are any better answers.

Comment: @aqwert Interestingly, I just created a test page with a `tel:` link and opened it on an Android 2.3 phone. I did not receive a prompt. Instead it took me directly to the Dialer app (but it does not actually auto dial). Is this what you experience on Android?

Comment: We have found that depending on the Android OS that it will either present the dialog or not. This has been a bit of a headache anyway since not only it might be OS specific but carrier also. We can detect based on the UserAgent string but there is no way to test all variants of the Android OS.

Comment: @BigMacAttack this seems to be vendor and device related... have seen different (inconsistent) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the complete spec you're asking for ... as far as I can tell from having fought with this too off and on for many months, there is no way to directly suppress the dialer dialog if OS thinks it's a phone number clicked in a page in a standalone browser.

I recall that it broadcasts an intent with "Tel:..." in the data parm. Since the vendor's dialer watches for that, the most you could hope for is to have your own dialer listen for that event too ... but then android would popup that annoying "complete action with" dialog AND they'd have to click yours, which would then have to launch yet another dialer intent.  (And would you then see your intercept dialer too ? )

As BigMacAttack points out, you could run it through webkit, change your tag to something other than "tel" and intercept that. Similarly, if the server pages could always be fed through a web-kit view, you could do what I did on couple of android and iOS apps:

```
// Android flavored
wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        boolean dialMe = false;                 

        if (url.indexOf("tel:") > -1) {  // PHONE permissions in AndroidManifest
                                             // see also DIAL_PHONE

            dialMe = myCustomDialerPopup ( Uri.parse(url) ) ; // display YOUR msg.

            if ( dialMe = true ) { // launch normal dialer

                Intent i =  new Intent( Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url) ) ;
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);  

            } else {
                            //// guess they don't want to call - oops marketing failed !
            } 
        }

        return true;  // or false to stop navigation.
    } 

}
```