# How do I detect whether user accepts or rejects call prompt on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

On iOS, when I do `<a href="tel:1234">call me</a>`, the prompt will pop up.

How do I detect in javascript whether user cancels or accepts to make the call?

`onBlur and onFocus` doesn't get fired on iOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer** 
No, this is not possible from a web page. It may be possible if you create an native application, by using custom prompt.

**Long answer**

This prompt is in response to the 911 exploit.
https://9to5mac.com/2017/03/06/911-ios-exploit/

You can see it added in 10.3 Release notes 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-10.3/

The behaviour is further explained in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

> The tel URL scheme is used to launch the Phone app on iOS devices and
>   initiate dialing of the specified phone number. When a user taps a
>   telephone link in a webpage, iOS displays an alert asking if the user
>   really wants to dial the phone number and initiates dialing if the
>   user accepts. When a user opens a URL with the tel scheme in a native
>   app, iOS 10.3 and later displays an alert and requires user
>   confirmation before dialing. (When this scenario occurs in versions of
>   iOS prior to 10.3, iOS initiates dialing without further prompting the
>   user and does not display an alert, although a native app can be
>   configured to display its own alert.)

According to [RFC 3966](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt): 11. Security Considerations

> Web clients and similar tools MUST NOT use the "tel" URI to place
>   telephone calls without the explicit consent of the user of that
>   client.  Placing calls automatically without appropriate user
>   confirmation may incur a number of risks, such as those described
>   below:
>
> o  Calls may incur costs.
>
> o  The URI may be used to place malicious or annoying calls.
>
> o  A call will take the user's phone line off-hook, thus preventing
>         its use.
>
> o  A call may reveal the user's possibly unlisted phone number to the
>         remote host in the caller identification data and may allow the
>         attacker to correlate the user's phone number with other
>         information, such as an e-mail or IP address.

Also see [Suppressing the native dialog when clicking on a tel: link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18524868/suppressing-the-native-dialog-when-clicking-on-a-tel-link)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to detect whether they cancel or call - not trying to bypass it.

Comment: The answer is correct, there's no way to do what you are asking.

Comment: Sadly, sometimes the answer to some programming questions is "this is not possible"